# Error HH12: Trying to use a non-local installation of Hardhat, which is not supported

Tags: npm, ethereum, solidity, npx, hardhat

I have installed hardhat properly because when I type
`npx hardhat` for, first time, it allows me to create the `config.js` files and sample projects.

The problem is I can't use the hardhat after that first command, and it keeps giving me the below error:

> Error HH12: Trying to use a non-local installation of Hardhat, which
> is not supported. Please install Hardhat locally using npm or Yarn,
> and try again.

I can't compile or do anything, and I have installed it and reinstalled it on new projects several times using only sample files, and still the same error.

So after that, if I do any `npx hardhat compile` or `npx hardhat` alone, I get the above error.. what can be the problem. it seems to get this error after generating the `config.js` file

I have tried only NextJS and hardhat ethers/waffle etc. dependencies installed on a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue over the last two days while trying to install Hardhat in a cloned repository using VS Code. This worked for me using the Powershell terminal.

In the project folder, use `npm ls` to check if Hardhat is already installed.
Then `npm -g ll` to check for a global installation, if it exists run `npm uninstall hardhat` then exit the terminal (and VS Code).

Repeat the above checks in a new terminal to ensure the uninstall is complete.
Create a new folder and follow the installation process as per the Hardhat docs, i.e:

1. `npm init -y`
2. `npm install --save-dev hardhat`
3. `npx hardhat` ("create a simple project")
4. `npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle chai @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers ethers`

Run `npx hardhat` to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i had figured it out but let me post the solution for others struggling.

The simple solution is to check the case when using Terminal. the folder names and directories are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I'd been struggling with this for a few hours, I'm pretty sure its **because I had VS code running** trying to run hardhat in PS.

Seems to be working fine now.

I'm a newbie to web3, and all these environment setup errors are infuriating.
I never had these problems 20 years ago, lol.